# Python live Entry in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I would like see the Tkinter Entry value live. When I'm typewriting, i see print 'downkey';. If i'm typing 4 character the one entry i see live the bottom in window ok,ok,ok,ok,etc.

```
from email . mime . multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email . mime . text import MIMEText
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *

import ConfigParser
import smtplib

class Example ( Frame ):

    def __init__ ( self, parent ):

        self . ini ()
        Frame . __init__ ( self, parent )
        self . parent = parent
        self . initUI ()

    def initUI ( self ):

        self . parent . title ( "Quit button" )
        self . style = Style ()
        self . style . theme_use ( "default" )
        self . pack ( fill = BOTH, expand = 1 )
        inputfield = Entry ( self ) # I would like see this entry the app. window bottom in live, when i'm typewriter. If i key down/press call one function is class.
        inputfield . place ( x = 10, y = 10 )
        quitButton = Button ( self, text = "Quit", command = self . quit )
        quitButton . place ( x = 50, y = 50 )

def main ():

    root = Tk ()
    root . geometry ( "250x150+300+300" )
    app = Example ( root )
    root . mainloop ()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    main ()
```

Comment: What's with the space between the `.`'s? Although it's grammatically correct, it's ugly... But anyway - what exactly is your question?

Comment: @JonClements I was going to start tinkering with an answer, but I had no idea you could use dots like that, so maybe I'm not the best person to do so :)

Comment: @RocketDonkey Yeah, also: `1.__str__` isn't valid attribute access, it's an invalid float, but `(1).__str__` or `1 . __str__` will work... Good ol' Python

Comment: @JonClements Haha, had no idea. Learn something new every day!

Comment: Could you translate "I would like see this entry the app. window bottom in live, when i'm typewriter. If i key down/press call one funtion is class" to English please?

Comment: If I keyboard press the inputfield Entry i would like call xyz function in the Example class. Sorry, I speak a very little english.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/6548837/ (see the answer there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call a function after typing in the entry field, you will have to use event handler and bind the entry field to event like press of return and some function xyz.
which means after pressing return, a function xyz can be called.

To update a message according to entry, you will need a variable string as argument to entry.

define a text variable globally:

```
m=StringVar()
```

in Eample class add:

you could add variable text to entry field

```
inputfield = Entry ( self,textvariable=m )

self.inputfield.bind('<Return>',self.xyz)  #to call xyz which you may want to define
```

and add textvariable to message to update it

```
message = Message(self,textvariable=m) #to update continuously the message which i hope you meant by "live"
```

Comment: inputfield = Entry ( self, textvariable = self . m )

Comment: inputfield . bind ( '<Key>', self . xyz )

Comment: def xyz ( self, varr ): print varr

Comment: <Tkinter.Event instance at 0x99885ac> ... Why?

Comment: def xyz ( self , event):

#event argument is required for event handler.