# python ttk : How to detect if at least one of the widgets of a frame is updated by the user?

Tags: python, combobox, frame, ttk

I have a frame that contains multiple entry and combobox widgets. The widgets are filled up with default values when the frame is populated.

I was wondering if there is a simple way to detect which entry/combobox widgets have been updated by the user.

If not, it would require me to go through all the entry/combobox widgets one by one and only store a new value if it is different than the default one.

If so I would be able to save time by only copying the values of the items that have changed without the need to compare them first.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand what you are trying to achieve, but the two options I can think are

1. iterate through each widget and compare to reference values (*the one you evoke in your question*)
2. bind to edits on those widgets and either store new values, or handle a list of edited widgets

The usual way to perform the former in GUI is through binding and callbacks. If you use `Entry` and `ttk.Combobox`, you can handle both with `StringVar` and `trace` bindings.

Here is a snippet (inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6549535)) illustrating callback *aware* of the edited widget. It is up to you to handle a damage list (with the widgets that have been edited) or a data structure with only modified value.

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

def callback(name, sv):
    print "{0}: {1}".format(name, sv.get())

root = Tk()

sv = StringVar()
sv.trace("w", lambda name, index, mode, sv=sv: callback("one", sv))
e = Entry(root, textvariable=sv)
e.pack()

sv = StringVar()
sv.trace("w", lambda name, index, mode, sv=sv: callback("two", sv))
e = Entry(root, textvariable=sv)
e.pack()

sv = StringVar()
box = ttk.Combobox(root, textvariable=sv)
box.pack()
box['values'] = ('X', 'Y', 'Z')
box.current(0)
sv.trace("w", lambda name, index, mode, sv=sv: callback("three", sv))

root.mainloop()
```