# How to pause a script with a Tkinter event?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating a simple class named Dialog. I only want it to return when **init** method is already finished.

```
from tkinter import *
class Dialog:
    def __set_data(self):
        self.data = self.entry_.get()
        self.top.destroy()
    def __init__(self, prompt_text = "Prompt:", submit_text = "OK", text_size = 5, button_size = 5,  main_window = Tk()):
        main_window.withdraw()
        top = self.top = Toplevel(main_window)
        Label(top, text=prompt_text).pack()
        self.entry_ = Entry(top)
        self.entry_.pack(padx = text_size)
        button = Button(top, text = submit_text, command = self.__set_data)
        button.pack(pady=button_size)

    def get_data(self):
        return self.data
    data = 0

a = Dialog();
print (a.get_data())
```

If you run this code, you will get the output 0. I want to the output only show up after the user input. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I don't think that you really want to postpone the `__init__` method returning.  If you do that, your code will never get to `tk.mainloop()`, and will never actually appear on screen.

Instead, what you want to do is be notified when the data in the `Entry` widget changes.  This is a pretty common thing to do in GUI toolkits; the way tkinter handles it is with Events and Bindings.  You can read about them generally [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm).

One way of performing your particular task (showing the data in `self.entry` once it has been changed by the user) might be to use the method [shown in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548837/how-do-i-get-an-event-callback-when-a-tkinter-entry-widget-is-modified).

Alternatively, you could add a `command` to your submit button ([see here](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-callbacks.htm)) and read the value of the entry in that method.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm new to Python and my native language isn't english. Can you add to the question the exactly code I need to add?

Comment: I dont know what to do!

Comment: @LucasHenrique As a start, you could try only printing the data from your `__set_data` method.  For anything more complicated than that, it's well worth having a look at the effbot articles I linked to, as they give a pretty good overview of how events/callbacks in Tk work.