# How can I store a tkinter Entry() value as a float value?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

How can I take a value a user inputs into a `tkinter Entry widget` and store it as a float? I have created a  `tkinter Entry widget` so the user can input a decimal value:

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
a = Entry()
a.pack()
number = float(a.get())
window.mainloop()
```

I get an error from `number = float(a.get())` that states: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''`. Is this because the tkinter Entry widget is empty without further configurations?

Edit: found solution: bind the `tkinter Entry widget` using `tkinter.Entry.bind()`. I set the parameters of `bind()` to `<Return>` followed by a comma and a `lambda function`.

Comment: Because the entry hand the value of "" (empty string) when the line `number = float(a.get())` was executed.

Comment: How would I execute `number = float(a.get())` only after the entry value is entered?

Comment: You would need to make an event callback function and trace it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548837/how-do-i-get-an-event-callback-when-a-tkinter-entry-widget-is-modified

Comment: I think what @Igor initially said is correct. `tkinter` programs are event-driven, which means you should only call `a.get()` in a callback function that is invoked when certain events occur. One way is to `a.bind('<Return>', my_function)` which will call the function whenever the Enter key is pressed (when the `Entry` widget has focus). Even then you will need to make sure the value isn't the empty string to avoid the same error.

Comment: Or bind it

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39058817/event-callback-after-a-tkinter-entry-widget?rq=1

Comment: @martineau Thanks, the binding method works perfectly for what I need.

Comment: All your script display and bindings should be in the main body of your script. Everything that should be performed after the window is displayed should go in the callback functions of the bindings.

Comment: @IgorDragushhak Makes sense now. Thank you for a simple-to-follow explanation!

Comment: ephemeralhappiness: That's good to hear. Sounds like you might be interested in [Best way to structure a tkinter application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466561/best-way-to-structure-a-tkinter-application)

Comment: Haha what are the odds...I reference that question for the GUI I'm working on for a research project. I'm a high school student fairly new to Python, but I'm learning a helluva lot because of people like you on stack overflow. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You may find this helpful.

```
from tkinter import *
try:

    window = Tk()
    some = StringVar()
    a = Entry(textvariable = some)
    a.pack()
    window.mainloop()

    number = float(some.get())
    print(number)
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid Value in The Entry Box")
```

Comment: This will give the error too. By default value of `Entry` Widget is `""` and `StringVar` will not do anything here. **This is not the answer.**

Comment: **Maybe with a proper `Trace` callback function to `DoubleVar`** with `if` condition should be more advisable.

Comment: DoubleVar Will also give a similar error when a string is received.