# Python Tkinter Autocomplete combobox with LIKE search?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, combobox, sqlite, tk-toolkit

I am trying to populate a Tkinter combobox with pre-defined values to select from. It is populating and I am able to type in and get suggestions. However, in order to do this I have to definitely know the first few characters. If I know some text in the middle or end of the string, its of no use because the combobox does only a **'LIKE%' search and not a '%LIKE%' search**.

Expected Output (Typing the word "Ceramic" fetches all names containing the string. **Note: This is not a Tkinter screenshot**):

[image]

This is my adaptation of the code till now, if anyone can suggest how to modify the *AutocompleteCombobox* class to do a LIKE search, it would be great.

The below working piece of code, as an example, has values "Cranberry" and "Strawberry" , my requirement is to type "berry" and get suggestions of both fruits.

```
import Tkinter
import ttk
import sqlite3


class AutocompleteCombobox(ttk.Combobox):

        def set_completion_list(self, completion_list):
                """Use our completion list as our drop down selection menu, arrows move through menu."""
                self._completion_list = sorted(completion_list, key=str.lower) # Work with a sorted list
                self._hits = []
                self._hit_index = 0
                self.position = 0
                self.bind('<KeyRelease>', self.handle_keyrelease)
                self['values'] = self._completion_list  # Setup our popup menu

        def autocomplete(self, delta=0):
                """autocomplete the Combobox, delta may be 0/1/-1 to cycle through possible hits"""
                if delta: # need to delete selection otherwise we would fix the current position
                        self.delete(self.position, Tkinter.END)
                else: # set position to end so selection starts where textentry ended
                        self.position = len(self.get())
                # collect hits
                _hits = []
                for element in self._completion_list:
                        if element.lower().startswith(self.get().lower()): # Match case insensitively
                                _hits.append(element)
                # if we have a new hit list, keep this in mind
                if _hits != self._hits:
                        self._hit_index = 0
                        self._hits=_hits
                # only allow cycling if we are in a known hit list
                if _hits == self._hits and self._hits:
                        self._hit_index = (self._hit_index + delta) % len(self._hits)
                # now finally perform the auto completion
                if self._hits:
                        self.delete(0,Tkinter.END)
                        self.insert(0,self._hits[self._hit_index])
                        self.select_range(self.position,Tkinter.END)

        def handle_keyrelease(self, event):
                """event handler for the keyrelease event on this widget"""
                if event.keysym == "BackSpace":
                        self.delete(self.index(Tkinter.INSERT), Tkinter.END)
                        self.position = self.index(Tkinter.END)
                if event.keysym == "Left":
                        if self.position < self.index(Tkinter.END): # delete the selection
                                self.delete(self.position, Tkinter.END)
                        else:
                                self.position = self.position-1 # delete one character
                                self.delete(self.position, Tkinter.END)
                if event.keysym == "Right":
                        self.position = self.index(Tkinter.END) # go to end (no selection)
                if len(event.keysym) == 1:
                        self.autocomplete()
                # No need for up/down, we'll jump to the popup
                # list at the position of the autocompletion


def test(test_list):
        """Run a mini application to test the AutocompleteEntry Widget."""
        root = Tkinter.Tk(className='AutocompleteCombobox')

        combo = AutocompleteCombobox(root)
        combo.set_completion_list(test_list)
        combo.pack()
        combo.focus_set()
        # I used a tiling WM with no controls, added a shortcut to quit
        root.bind('<Control-Q>', lambda event=None: root.destroy())
        root.bind('<Control-q>', lambda event=None: root.destroy())
        root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
        test_list = ('apple', 'banana', 'Cranberry', 'dogwood', 'alpha', 'Acorn', 'Anise', 'Strawberry' )
        test(test_list)
```

Comment: Please make a [mcve], iow with example data included and without a SQLite call that we can't use.

Comment: @Novel Apologies, I have made several edits and you will also be able to run the code now.

Comment: How do you envision the user experience? You can't have selected text before *and* after what the user is typing.

Comment: It is quite possible and as an end user, I have used the same feature in another product and trying to replicate the same. Assume there are 100 types of berries in the inventory and need to select one, all I need to do is type "berry" and scroll through the 100 and select which one I want. Note that the dropdown list will have smaller and smaller subsets of results each for "b" , "be", "ber", "berr", "berry" as I keep typing.

Comment: can't you use `if "berry" in "Cranberry"` (`if "berry" in "Strawberry"`). In your code it will be `if self.get().lower() in element.lower()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suspect you need

```
 if self.get().lower() in element.lower():
```

instead of

```
 if element.lower().startswith(self.get().lower()):
```

to get data like with `%LIKE%` in database

---

But I don't know if you get good effect because this `Combobox` replaces text with suggestion so if you type `be` then it finds `Cranberry` and put in place `be` and you can't write `ber`.

Maybe you should display `Cranberry` as separated (dropdown) list, or popup tip.

Or maybe you will have to use `string.find()` to highlight correct place in `Cranberry` and continue to type `ber` in correct place.

---

**EDIT:** example how to use `Entry` and `Listbox` to display filtered list

In `listbox_update` I added sorting list (comparing lower case strings)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import tkinter as tk

def on_keyrelease(event):
    
    # get text from entry
    value = event.widget.get()
    value = value.strip().lower()
    
    # get data from test_list
    if value == '':
        data = test_list
    else:
        data = []
        for item in test_list:
            if value in item.lower():
                data.append(item)                

    # update data in listbox
    listbox_update(data)
    
    
def listbox_update(data):
    # delete previous data
    listbox.delete(0, 'end')
    
    # sorting data 
    data = sorted(data, key=str.lower)

    # put new data
    for item in data:
        listbox.insert('end', item)


def on_select(event):
    # display element selected on list
    print('(event) previous:', event.widget.get('active'))
    print('(event)  current:', event.widget.get(event.widget.curselection()))
    print('---')


# --- main ---

test_list = ('apple', 'banana', 'Cranberry', 'dogwood', 'alpha', 'Acorn', 'Anise', 'Strawberry' )

root = tk.Tk()

entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack()
entry.bind('<KeyRelease>', on_keyrelease)

listbox = tk.Listbox(root)
listbox.pack()
#listbox.bind('<Double-Button-1>', on_select)
listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', on_select)
listbox_update(test_list)

root.mainloop()
```

At start with full list

[image]

Later only with filtered items

[image]

---

**EDIT: 2020.07.21**

If you want to use `<KeyPress>` then you have to change `on_keyrelease` and use `event.char`, `event.keysym` and/or `event.keycode` because `KeyPress` is executed before `tkinter` update text in `Entry` and you have to add `event.char` to text in `Entry` (or remove last char when you press `backspace`)

```
if event.keysym == 'BackSpace':
    value = event.widget.get()[:-1]  # remove last char
else:
    value = event.widget.get() + event.char  # add new char at the end
```

It may need other changes for other special keys `Ctrl+A`, `Ctrl+X`, `Ctrl+C`, `Ctrl+E`, etc. and it makes big problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import tkinter as tk

def on_keypress(event):

    print(event)
    print(event.state & 4) # Control
    print(event.keysym == 'a')
    # get text from entry
    if event.keysym == 'BackSpace':
        # remove last char
        value = event.widget.get()[:-1]
    elif (event.state & 4): # and (event.keysym in ('a', 'c', 'x', 'e')):
        value = event.widget.get()
    else:
        # add new char at the end        
        value = event.widget.get() + event.char
    #TODO: other special keys

    value = value.strip().lower()

    # get data from test_list
    if value == '':
        data = test_list
    else:
        data = []
        for item in test_list:
            if value in item.lower():
                data.append(item)                

    # update data in listbox
    listbox_update(data)


def listbox_update(data):
    # delete previous data
    listbox.delete(0, 'end')

    # sorting data 
    data = sorted(data, key=str.lower)

    # put new data
    for item in data:
        listbox.insert('end', item)


def on_select(event):
    # display element selected on list
    print('(event) previous:', event.widget.get('active'))
    print('(event)  current:', event.widget.get(event.widget.curselection()))
    print('---')


# --- main ---

test_list = ('apple', 'banana', 'Cranberry', 'dogwood', 'alpha', 'Acorn', 'Anise', 'Strawberry' )

root = tk.Tk()

entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack()
entry.bind('<KeyPress>', on_keypress)

listbox = tk.Listbox(root)
listbox.pack()
#listbox.bind('<Double-Button-1>', on_select)
listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', on_select)
listbox_update(test_list)

root.mainloop()
```

---

**BTW:**

You can also use `textvariable` in `Entry` with `StringVar` and `trace` which executes function when `StringVar` changes content.

```
var_text = tk.StringVar()
var_text.trace('w', on_change)

entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var_text)
entry.pack()
```

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import tkinter as tk

def on_change(*args):
    #print(args)
          
    value = var_text.get()
    value = value.strip().lower()

    # get data from test_list
    if value == '':
        data = test_list
    else:
        data = []
        for item in test_list:
            if value in item.lower():
                data.append(item)                

    # update data in listbox
    listbox_update(data)


def listbox_update(data):
    # delete previous data
    listbox.delete(0, 'end')

    # sorting data 
    data = sorted(data, key=str.lower)

    # put new data
    for item in data:
        listbox.insert('end', item)


def on_select(event):
    # display element selected on list
    print('(event) previous:', event.widget.get('active'))
    print('(event)  current:', event.widget.get(event.widget.curselection()))
    print('---')

# --- main ---

test_list = ('apple', 'banana', 'Cranberry', 'dogwood', 'alpha', 'Acorn', 'Anise', 'Strawberry' )

root = tk.Tk()

var_text = tk.StringVar()
var_text.trace('w', on_change)

entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var_text)
entry.pack()

listbox = tk.Listbox(root)
listbox.pack()
#listbox.bind('<Double-Button-1>', on_select)
listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', on_select)
listbox_update(test_list)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tried using `if self.get().lower() in element.lower(): ` as you say the response is getting filled automatically with the closest match and subsequently scrolling with up/down arrows may or may not fetch the expected values. I am not sure how to use `string.find()` , I am adding a screenshot of the actual functionality to the original question for better self explanation.

Comment: command `"Cranberry".find("be")` gives position of `"be"` in `"Cranberry"` and you will know which part to highlight and where to put cursor when yoou type text.

Comment: Hmm, I tried to incorporate it into the existing program but not sure how to. I am relatively new to python. However I did run it on the Python shell and see that it returns the position of the text as a numerical value as follows:

`>>> "Cranberry".find("be")
4
>>> "Cranberry".find("b")
4`

 I am not sure of how to process this numerical values further, so looks like I will have to live with `element.lower().startswith` for now.

Comment: frankly it would be easier if you use `Entry` only for entering text, and `Listbox` for displaying matching elements - without all this autocompletion and highlighting.

Comment: I am new to this, can you give me a sample with the same variables? It does sound like a good idea and I am able to envision it but not clear how to bind the values between `Entry` and `Listbox`

Comment: one moment, I thought I have example on GitHub but I have to create new one.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it is working like a charm! I also found this on GitHub
https://gist.github.com/Nikola-K/10364096/060bedf9e34eb4d753ba72b53163aadd9bb2769e

Comment: I have 2 lists with different values, I want to update code in such a way that on_keyRelease should be accepting listname as parameter so that autocomplete feature will sort items in corresponding lists. How do i pass listname here entry2.bind('<KeyRelease>', on_keyrelease)

Comment: Great solution! Any way to do this on KeyPress rather than KeyRelease? I tried replacing the entry bind but then the list seems to lag by a keypress

Comment: @evn you may not be able to use the above solution directly but combine the above with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/detect-key-press-in-python

Comment: @evn why do you want to use `KeyPress` ? There is `<KeyPress>` but it is executed before it changes value in `Entry` so it may need totally different code in `on_keyrelease`. It may need to use `event.keycode`, `event.char` or `event.keysym` and it may need to block `KeyRelease` in `Entry` - so it will be much more complicated.

Comment: I added code with `KeyPress` but it doesn't resolve problem with special keys like `Ctrl+X` which removes text but only when text is selected, etc. `KeyPress` runs function before `Entry` changes text (and process chars like `Ctrl+X` and selection)  so you have to process special keys on your own - and it makes big problem.

Comment: @mbadullah The reason I wanted to use KeyPress is to avoid the feeling of delay while waiting for KeyRelease. I was able to run the operation on change of the stringvar by combining the above solution with the following https://stackoverflow.com/a/6549535/

Comment: @evn I don't know what system you use but I don't feel delay on Linux Mint. Maybe because I release key at one - when I keep little long then it starts repeating key. Using `SrtingVar` I also don't feel delay - and it doesn't use `KeyPress`

Comment: @furas As a user, I expect to see my keystrokes recognized on `KeyPress`, as this is the functionality I am accustomed to while typing. There is no actual delay, however I _perceive_ a delay due to the discrepancy between the moment I _expect_ my strokes to be reflected (`KeyPress`), and the moment my strokes are _actually_ reflected (`KeyRelease`). This perceived delay is remedied by updating listbox when `StringVar` is changed, as that happens almost immediately after the key is pressed.

Comment: @furas I am running the code on a Windows 10 server through Microsoft Remote Desktop on MacOS Mojave