# I have 50000 company list and I created this combobox so when I type company name it does not give me suggestions

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

When I start type Are so ARAMCO and Armani should come up.
My requirement is that when I start typing i should get suggestions.
My list is really huge around 50000, so it would be really hard to get exact company name unless suggestions popups.
My requirement is similar to below link but I will be happy even if I type first few letter of the starting word and all matching word comes on top.

[Python Tkinter Autocomplete combobox with LIKE search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47839813/python-tkinter-autocomplete-combobox-with-like-search)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
window = Tk()
window.title("Welcome to Combobox")
window.geometry('350x200')
lbl = Label(window, text="Select Company")
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)
combo = Combobox(window)
combo['values']= ("Google", "Facebook", "Twitter", "Microsoft", "Apple", "ATT", "Orange", "Target", "Macys" "Other", "Airtel", "Armani", "Aramco")
combo.grid(column=1, row=0)
def clicked():

    res = "Selected Company is " + combo.get()
    lbl.configure(text= res)
    print (combo.get())

btn = Button(window, text="Click Me", command=clicked)
btn.grid(column=2, row=0)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Suggestions mean, if I type M then all company name starting with M should start coming and the I type Mi then all company name start with Mi should come first.

Comment: It does not autocomplete when I start typing.

Comment: @Artemis, No this is not duplicate. My requirement is different. I have edited the question and tried to explain little more.

Comment: I have added an answer which I hope meets your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

This is an adaptation from [this module (MIT licensed)](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578253-an-entry-with-autocompletion-for-the-tkinter-gui/), combined with your code to achieve what you describe. I hope it helps.

```
from tkinter import *

class AutocompleteEntry(Entry):
    def __init__(self, lista, *args, **kwargs):

        Entry.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.lista = lista        
        self.var = self["textvariable"]
        if self.var == '':
            self.var = self["textvariable"] = StringVar()

        self.var.trace('w', self.changed)
        self.bind("<Right>", self.selection)
        self.bind("<Up>", self.up)
        self.bind("<Down>", self.down)
        self.haslb = False
        self.lb_up = False

    def changed(self, name, index, mode):
        if self.var.get() == '':
            if self.haslb:
                self.lb.destroy()
            self.lb_up = False
        else:
            words = self.comparison()
            if words:            
                if not self.lb_up:
                    self.lb = Listbox()
                    self.haslb = True
                    self.lb.bind("<Double-Button-1>", self.selection)
                    self.lb.bind("<Right>", self.selection)
                    self.lb.place(x=self.winfo_x(), y=self.winfo_y()+self.winfo_height())
                    self.lb_up = True

                self.lb.delete(0, END)
                for w in words:
                    self.lb.insert(END,w)
            else:
                if self.lb_up:
                    self.lb.destroy()
                    self.lb_up = False

    def selection(self, event): 

        if self.lb_up:
            self.var.set(self.lb.get(ACTIVE))
            self.lb.destroy()
            self.lb_up = False
            self.icursor(END) 
            res = "Selected Company is " + self.var.get()
            lbl.configure(text= res)
            print (self.var.get())

    def up(self, event):

        if self.lb_up:
            if self.lb.curselection() == ():
                index = '0'
            else:
                index = self.lb.curselection()[0]
            if index != '0':                
                self.lb.selection_clear(first=index)
                index = str(int(index)-1)                
                self.lb.selection_set(first=index)
                self.lb.activate(index) 

    def down(self, event):

        if self.lb_up:
            if self.lb.curselection() == ():
                index = '0'
            else:
                index = self.lb.curselection()[0]
            if index != END:                        
                self.lb.selection_clear(first=index)
                index = str(int(index)+1)        
                self.lb.selection_set(first=index)
                self.lb.activate(index) 

    def comparison(self):
        listb=list(self.lista)
        ret=[]
        for w in listb:
            if w[:len(self.var.get())]==self.var.get():
                ret.append(w)
            listb.remove(w)
        for i in listb:
            ret.append(i)
        return ret

window = Tk()
window.title("Welcome to Combobox")
window.geometry('350x200')
lbl = Label(window, text="Select Company")
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)
companies=("Google", "Facebook", "Twitter", "Microsoft", "Apple", "ATT", "Orange", "Target", "Macys" "Other", "Airtel", "Armani", "Aramco")
entry = AutocompleteEntry(companies, window)
entry.grid(column=1, row=0)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you Artemis for trying but it does not work as I have my list huge. My requirement is similar to below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47839813/python-tkinter-autocomplete-combobox-with-like-search

Comment: If you mean that 'tt' should return 'A**TT**' and 'Twi**tt**er', then sure, I will edit it.

Comment: Hi Artemis, my first requirement is creating combobox and that combobox will get value from column B excel sheet. This sheet has around 50000 rows with 3 columns column B has company name and column C has Category. Please see above program I have provided complete program. In your Listbox my excel sheets data is not coming as a list.

Comment: So you want it to fetch data from excel as well? That's definitely not in your question.

Comment: I am sorry that I have mentioned in the question that will be extracting data from excel. But it is almost impossible keeping 50000 data manually. My code is working fine except, It is not autocomplete when I type first word so lets say there is a company name "ZUMBA PVT LTD" I have to scroll down all the way down and select this company manually.

Comment: I want if I type ZUMBA all the company starting with ZUMBA should come in first few row so that I could select them easily

Comment: @Majeed That's exactly what this program should do, except the fetching from excel. I have no experience with excel-vba and so would not be able to do that, but if you load the list to the variable `companies`, it should work.