# Tkinter label updating in real time

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this code. My goal is for "chores_earned_0_label" to display the amount of money earned. This is calculated by multiplying the values contained in the entry fields of "chores_amount_0_sv" and "chores_price_0_sv". It would have to be a part of the GUI mainloop, but I don't know how to incorporate this calculation into the program. Thank you very much

```
from tkinter import *

GUI = Tk()

chore_0 = Frame(GUI)
chore_0.grid(column=0, sticky=W)
chores_name_0_sv = StringVar()
chores_name_0_entry = Entry(chore_0, textvariable=chores_name_0_sv).pack(side=LEFT)
chores_amount_0_sv = StringVar()
chores_amount_0_entry = Entry(chore_0, textvariable=chores_amount_0_sv).pack(side=LEFT)
chores_price_0_sv = StringVar()
chores_price_0_entry = Entry(chore_0, textvariable=chores_price_0_sv).pack(side=LEFT)

chores_earned_0_label = Label(chore_0, textvariable=).pack(side=LEFT)

GUI.mainloop()
```

Comment: This will answer your question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548837/how-do-i-get-an-event-callback-when-a-tkinter-entry-widget-is-modified

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get an event callback when a Tkinter Entry widget is modified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548837/how-do-i-get-an-event-callback-when-a-tkinter-entry-widget-is-modified)

Comment: I don't understand what is callback or any of this. I'm trying to infer what it mean but it's hard