# TypeError : return_entry takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given ; The converse seems true. Fails with no argument

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror, tkinter-entry

Using Windows 10 , python 3.5 , tkinter 8.6

```
def return_entry() :
    content = ew.get()
    print(content)

ew = Entry(root, font = myfont, width = 30)
ew.place(x = 170, y = 100)
ew.bind('<Return>', return_entry)
```

run as above get TypeError. If any string is given as argument , eg  return_entry(anything) the code runs fine. Error message seems to contradict itself.

Comment: Please include the full error message.

Comment: The function that you bind must take one parameter: the Event that caused its invocation. See, e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548837/how-do-i-get-an-event-callback-when-a-tkinter-entry-widget-is-modified).

Comment: The full error message is :  Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1558, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: return_entry() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: Precisely my point: you must provide the Event parameter even if you do not use it.

Comment: Thanks, but what is an Event parameter ? Searched & found "event handler", "event type" and "event modifier". Under handler found the arcane statement "The function included as the event handler will be passed an event object which includes details about the event that was triggered, meaning you should include a parameter to be assigned the object in your function".  Regarding the above comment that the parameter should be the event : the event is the Return key.   def return_entry('<Return>') or (<Return>) both yield SyntaxError.  (Return) does work, but so does (anything) .

Comment: Have you looked at the example? I provided a link.

Comment: Yes, the example uses a StringVar.  The .get() method is said to return the Entry's text as a string.  Admit I don't understand the difference between the string ( yielded by get ) & a StringVar in a dynamically typed  language.

Comment: Look at the doSomething function in the first answer. It does not use StringVar.